# potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

I am getting error with below description when I start my Hue 3.9.0 in Cloudera 5.5.0 in VirtualBox.

Error:

```
Checking current configuration

Configuration files located in /etc/hue/conf.empty

Potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue.

hadoop.hdfs_clusters.default.webhdfs_url

Current value: http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1

Failed to create temporary file "/tmp/hue_config_validation.6370998130067515579"
```

**Note:**

**I tried restarting the Hue server with:**

To start the Hue Server:

```
$ sudo service hue start
```

To stop the Hue Server:

```
$ sudo service hue stop
```

**I also tried to restart all the servers with:**

```
$ for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-*` ; do sudo service $x stop ; done

$ for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-*` ; do sudo service $x start ; done
```

**I also tried to restart all the servers in Hue page, But I am not able to find service tab to restart the servers. May I know how do i do this?**

Please someone help me to resolve this.

Let me know if you need more details on this.

Thanks & Regards,

Nitish

Comment: Does you HDFS has a /tmp directory with 1777 permissions?